# Cocoapod "error: could not build module 'UIKit'"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, mupdf, podspec

I'm trying to fit MuPDF into a podspec. That's not going as good as I want it to though...

```
error: could not build module 'UIKit'
```

This is the error I get every time I try to `pod lib lint`. I get it in two flavours though, depending on the exact contents of the podspec. But before that, some context!

**tl;dr**: My brain can't process MuPDF and its static library dependencies to make a nice podspec out of it. Can you help?

---

### File layout

So the library is MuPDF (http://mupdf.com); I cloned their git repository. It comes with a bunch of `.m` files, but the main library is written in C and has several dependencies. So we end up with a few static libraries (`.a` files). The file layout looks something like this:

```
mupdf/
  # objc files
  platform/ios/common.{h,m}
  platform/ios/Classes/*.{h,m}

  # headers and static libraries
  include/**/*.h
  platform/ios/thirdparty/*.a
```

The `include` folder contains the headers required by the libraries in `platform/ios/thirdparty`. These headers are included by `platform/ios/common.h`.

### Podspec

And my podspec looks something like this:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  # <enter usual podspec yada yada here>

  s.source_files  = "platform/ios/Classes/**/*.{h,m}", "platform/ios/common.{h,m}", "include/**/*.h"
  s.public_header_files = "platform/ios/Classes/**/*.h"
  s.header_mappings_dir = "include"

  s.libraries = "z"
  s.vendored_libraries = "platform/ios/thirdparty/*"
end
```

---

Based on that (and a variation of the podspec), I get two different errors.

### Symbol redefinition error

With this exact podspec configuration, I get the following errors:

```
- ERROR |  /<path>/mupdf/include/mupdf/fitz/math.h:97:8:
           error: redefinition of 'fz_point_s'
- NOTE  |  /<path>/mupdf/include/mupdf/fitz/math.h:97:8:
           note: previous definition is here
- ERROR |  /<path>/mupdf/include/mupdf/fitz/math.h:121:8:
            error: redefinition of 'fz_rect_s'
- NOTE  |  /<path>/mupdf/include/mupdf/fitz/math.h:121:8:
           note: previous definition is here

# etc. etc.

- NOTE  |  Target Support Files/Pods-mupdf/Pods-mupdf-prefix.pch:2:9:
           fatal error: could not build module 'UIKit'
```

### Circular dependency error

If I comment out the `s.public_header_files` line, I end up with a circular dependency error. So weird!

```
- NOTE  |  /privateTarget Support Files/Pods-mupdf/Pods-mupdf-umbrella.h:1:9:
           fatal error: cyclic dependency in module 'UIKit':
           UIKit -> Foundation -> CoreFoundation -> MuPDF -> UIKit
```

---

### Conclusion

My brain hurts, please help!

Comment: Can i download your project somewhere? Since you add MuPDF and that one has a viral copy-left license, yours is also automatically under the Affero GNU GPL v3 (which btw, is incompatible with the App Store, so you legally can't submit your app)

Answer (score 4):

I am not really sure what is going on with your PodSpec, sorry. It is probably something to do with how you resolved the math.h header file conflict - it is annoyingly tricky to get this right in a pod spec.

I have just created a [CocoaPod for MuPDF](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MuPDF), and created an [example application based on that pod](https://github.com/jogu/MuPDF-example), and all seems to work fine.

For reference here is my pod spec (note that this is now out of date; please refer to the [published mupdf pod spec](https://cocoapods.org/pods/MuPDF) for one compatible with the latest version of mupdf and latest CocoaPods):

```
# podspec for MuPDF
#
# Copyright (C) 2015 Joseph Heenan <joseph@heenan.me.uk>

Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = "MuPDF"
  s.version          = "1.7"
  s.summary          = "A lightweight PDF and XPS viewer."
  s.description      = <<-DESC
                       MuPDF is a small, fast, and yet complete PDF viewer. 
                       It supports PDF 1.7 with transparency, encryption, 
                       hyperlinks, annotations, searching and more. It also
                       reads XPS and OpenXPS documents.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = "http://www.mupdf.com/"
  s.license          = { :type => "Affero GNU GPL v3", :file => 'COPYING' }
  s.author           = "Artifex Software Inc"
  s.source           = { :git => "https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/mupdf.git", :tag => s.version.to_s }

  s.platform     = :ios, '6.1'
  s.requires_arc = false

  s.source_files = 'platform/ios/Classes/**/*.[mh]', 'platform/ios/common.[mh]'
  s.resources = 'platform/ios/*.png', 'platform/android/res/drawable-ldpi/*.png'

  s.public_header_files = "platform/ios/Classes/**/*.h", "platform/ios/common.h"

  # See https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1437
  s.preserve_paths = "include/*", "include/**/*"

  s.prepare_command = <<-CMD
      # I tried --depth 1 here but it failed with git error "fatal: reference is not a tree:"
      git submodule update --init
      cd platform/ios

      # build the various .a files
      # release armv7 + arm64
      xcodebuild -scheme MuPDF -configuration Release CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
      # release i386 + x86_64
      xcodebuild -scheme MuPDF -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO

      # combine into fat libraries
      cd ../../build/
      for i in curl freetype jbig2dec jpeg mujs mupdf openjpeg z; do
          LIB=lib${i}.a
          lipo -create -output $LIB release-ios-i386-x86_64/$LIB release-ios-armv7-arm64/$LIB
      done
CMD

  s.vendored_libraries = "build/*.a"

  s.xcconfig = {
    # we have a math.h which conflicts with the system math.h unless
    # we disable header maps
    'USE_HEADERMAP' => 'NO',
    'HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"$(PODS_ROOT)/Target Support Files/Pods"',

    'USER_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS' => '"${PODS_ROOT}/MuPDF/include"',

    'ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS' => 'NO'
  }

end
```

Comment: Looks brilliant! Will try!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by deleting and adding UIKit.framework in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries and set project's minimum iOS Version was 6.0.

Comment: Doesn't work sadly. I tried adding UIKit, Foundation and CoreFoundation to `s.frameworks` but it didn't solve it either.